# making class accessible from class path in dynamic class loading

Tags: java, classpath

I have a project created in Eclipse, and I defined an interface and a class for dynamic class loading, the class is in the project directory, 
so I have this code in my project:

```
if (handlerClassName != null) 
    {
         TypeHandler typeHandler = null;
         try {
             typeHandler = (TypeHandler) 
            (Class.forName(handlerClassName).newInstance());
```

but I get this exception:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: "handlerClassName"

what should I do to make the JVM recognize the class "handlerClassName" in my project?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the full qualified classname including the entire package, e.g. `java.lang.String` instead of the short name like `string`. If it is actually not in a package, then fix it so that it's in a package. Packageless classes are namely invisible for classes in a package.

Comment: Thanks Balusc, you're right, I had to change it to 
(Class.forName("homework4." + handlerClassName).newInstance());
and it's working now.

Comment: You're welcome. According to the [Sun Java Naming Conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/html/CodeConventions.doc8.html), however, classnames ought to start with UpperCase.

Comment: I have it capitalised in the project, handlerClassName was just an alias.

Comment: Fine. In the future try to avoid this kind of red herrings :)

Comment: I had another question but i know the answer now.